# How to pass argument to React Redux middleware inside mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

The situation is I am creating a single board which will hold a collection of note cards (each note has an id, title and body), and each note card will have a button to delete it. Also the application will be syncing with firebase, so my main question is how to pass arguments to middlewares AND do it inside of mapDispatchToProps. The following is my code to point out where my success with middleware and where I am currently blocked.

To hydrate the app on startup, I dispatch a middleware function that gets the data from firebase, and then dispatches actions handled by reducers and finally gets updated by the container/presentation component.

Middleware function:

```
export function hydrateApp(dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: 'PENDING'});
    fireBaseDBRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        let firebaseNotes = snapshot.val()
        let notes = [];
        // populate notes using firebaseNotes, nothing exciting
        dispatch({ type: 'DONE', notes: notes });
        // the 'DONE' action.type is handled by the reducer and passes data
        // to the container component successfully
    }).catch(e => {
        dispatch({type: 'ERROR', error: e});
    });
}
```

Container component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
        notes: state.boardReducer.notes
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addNote: () => {
            dispatch(boardMiddleware.createNote);
        }
    };
};

const BoardContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(BoardPresentation);
```

So far so good, and this is what I added to the same middleware and container component files to handle delete scenarios.

Middleware function:

```
export function deleteNote(id) {
    return (dispatch) => {
       dispatch({type: 'PENDING'});
       //firebase stuff happening here
       dispatch((type: 'DONE'});
    }
}
```

Container component:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addNote: () => {
            dispatch(boardMiddleware.createNote);
        },
        removeNote: (id) => {
            dispatch(boardMiddleware.deleteNote(id));
        }
    };
};
```

The problem is that deleteNote gets called non-stop on startup, I don't even need to click the button.
I know the code presented may not make a whole bunch of sense, but the crux of my problem is that I need to some how pass an `id` to the middleware function when the user clicks on the button, and because I'm passing the function as a prop, it for some reasons decides to just call it a million times.

I could call `boardMiddleware.deleteNote` function inside the presentation component just like the examples in the official redux page do, but I'm wondering if there is a way of doing it the way I'm trying to do.
I also thought about binding the argument into the middleware function, but that also doesn't feel right, something like this

```
removeNote: (id) => {
     dispatch(boardMiddleware.deleteNote.bind(id));
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Try: `dispatch(() => boardMiddleware.deleteNote(id));`

Comment: What does the `onClick` handler look like? Sounds like it might not be a function, but a call, e.g. `onClick={this.props.deleteNote(someId)}`

Comment: The `onClick` handler just uses `this.props.removeNote`

Comment: Your 'middleware function' is just an action creator. You might be confusing some concepts here. Middlewares are used to catch actions before they reach the reducer and run side effects like logging etc.